# I can use my watch to ping my phone, but how can i use my phone to ping my watch

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch and one if its most useful functions is that I can swipe up and tap the ping iPhone icon to make my iPhone beep at me. This saves my bacon 4 or 5 times each week when I misplace my phone around the house. But I can’t find how to do the opposite. I sometimes misplace my watch and I want to be able to ping it from my phone, but there isn’t an option that I can find in the Watch app on my phone. I also looked in control center and don’t see an option there. Is there a way for me to ping my watch from my phone? Or is this just something Apple didn’t think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a way for you to do this so long as you have Find My iPhone activated in your iCloud settings. If so, do the following:

1. On your iPhone launch the Find iPhone app
2. In the bottom half of the screen you should see all of your devices, including your Apple Watch
3. Tap on the Apple Watch listing
4. Now at the bottom centre of the next screen you’ll see the word "Actions" - tap on this
5. Now tap on the Play Sound option
6. Your Apple Watch will now vibrate and play a sound until you dismiss it

**NOTE:** You can also do this from other Apple devices, or from logging into iCloud from a web browser on any computer.

For more information, refer to [If your Apple Watch is lost or stolen](https://support.apple.com/HT207024) on Apple's website.

Comment: Beat me to the answer :) You can consider adding this link if it makes the instructions easier for OP to follow: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207024

Comment: @NimeshNeema Good idea, I'll do that now. Don't forget though, you can always edit someone else's answer (even one from a moderator)! :)